# How to delete a vowel from a string in javascript without time out?

Tags: javascript, search

I was trying to solve a challenge, the question was simply a search and delete thing in javascript and I am a newbie to javascript. I wrote this but the execution was timed out. why? and how can I make it correct?

```js
function disemvowel(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++) {
    while (strSplit[i].search("a")) {
      strSplit[i] = strSplit[i].replace(/\/a/g,'');
    }
    while( strSplit[i].search("o")) {
      strSplit[i] = strSplit[i].replace(/\/o/g,'');
    }
    while (strSplit[i].search("u")) {
      strSplit[i] = strSplit[i].replace(/\/u/g,'');
    }
    while (strSplit[i].search("i")) {
      strSplit[i] = strSplit[i].replace(/\/i/g,'');
    }
    while (strSplit[i].search("e")) {
      strSplit[i] = strSplit[i].replace(/\/e/g,'');
    }
  }

  return strSplit;
}
```

Comment: umm, what do you want to achieve..? i saw too much `for` and `while` it doesnt feelss good..

Comment: I want to find every vowel in the input string and delete them and finally return a string without any vowels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `/\/a/` will replace `/a`s - that is, `a`s that are preceeded by forward slashes. This is *not* the same as `.search("a")`, which just searches for the one character `a` - this will result in an infinite loop.

Another problem is that `.search` will return `0` if the letter is at the 0th index of the string (falsey), and `-1` if the letter is not found in the string (truthy). This will result in another infinite loop.

Use a single regular expression replacement instead:

```
const disemvowel = str => str.replace(/[aeiou]/ig, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate this much. You execution timed out because you have a lot of unnecessary loops in your code.

```
function disemvowel(str) {
  return str.replace(/[aeiou]+/ig, '');
}
```

This replaces every vowel with nothing, and returns the string withouth vowels.

Comment: it did replace every vowel in every word with nothing, except the word "LOL", why?

Comment: I forgot the `i` in the regex, it didn't replace `O` because the regex was case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this you can simply use regEx to remove vowel

```
var stringWithoutVowel=str.replace(/[aeiou]/ig,'');
```